# Convergent Continuous Maps are Homotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology, continuity, homotopy-theory

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of continuous functions converging to $f:\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^l$ in the topology of compact convergence.  In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3615750/existence-of-a-transversal-map-prevents-density/3616368?noredirect=1#comment7434905_3616368) the answer says that eventually we can related the two by the (sequence of) homotopies
$$
F_n(x,t) = tf_n(x) + (1-t)f(x).
$$
But why can we do this evenutally?

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question by writing down the $F_n$? I checked the post you linked to and it doesn't seem to me that what you describe above appears in it.

Comment: Yes moishe talks about the "linear homotopy"

Comment: I think he uses the term "straight-line homotopy" (which is also called a "linear homotopy"), but his domains are different. Such linear homotopies always exist if your codomain is $\mathbb{R}^l$ (or any convex subset of it). As I pointed out, you answered your own question by writing down $F_n$. However, Moishe's functions are not defined as maps between Euclidean spaces. This is why *he* requires "sufficiently large $i$". Namely so that the image of $f_i$ (large $i$) is contained in a coordinate neighbourhood.

Comment: Ah ok!  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**All** maps $f,g : X \to \mathbb R^l$ are homotopic via the straight-line homotopy
$H(x,t) = tf(x) + (1-t)g(x)$.